# Diferencia entre Interface y Abstract class (particularmente en PHP)

Tags: php, poo

Tengo una duda que me come la cabeza y busqué en San Google pero encuentro respuestas sólo técnicas y no me ayudan mucho.

Quisiera que pudieran decirme de una manera sencilla y clara (si se quiere) la diferencia entre una interface y una abstract class, más precisamente en PHP.

Comment: Para los votantes a cerrar esta pregunta, existen similares en SOen que no han sido cerradas puesto que tienen una respuesta basada en conocimiento y experiencia: http://stackoverflow.com/q/761194/1065197 http://stackoverflow.com/q/56867/1065197

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Piensa en una interfaz como un contrato. La interfaz define qué se debe hacer (las funciones a implementar) pero no define cómo se debe hacer (cómo deben ser implementadas). Las clases abstractas, por el contrario, son clases que poseen atributos y funciones definidas (el qué y el cómo) pero que a su vez pueden solo definir qué debe hacerse (el qué), conocidas como funciones abstractas.